# Can not create a sender view for the envelope created by template Id in docusign

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi

I am trying to create an embedded view of an Envelope that I created using a `TempplateId` of a template created at my docusign account but the `envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope` doesn't work.

Here's my method that creates the envelope for a User taking in the template Id

```
private string MakeEnvelope(string signerEmail, string signerName, string templateId)
        {

            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

            // Data for this method
            // signerEmail 
            // signerName
            // ccEmail
            // ccName
            // templateId

            EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition
            {
                TemplateId = templateId,
                Status = "created"
            };

            TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole();
            signer1.Email = signerEmail;
            signer1.Name = signerName;
            signer1.RoleName = "Customer";

            //Company tab for signer
            Company companyTab = new Company
            {
                Value = "Systems Limited",
                TabLabel = "0b640933-9224-48e7-b8bc-adf388b63ac5"
            };

            Company[] companyTabs = new Company[] { companyTab };

            signer1.Tabs = new Tabs { CompanyTabs = new List<Company>(companyTabs) };
            //Company tab for signer

            env.TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole> { signer1 };

            var options = new ReturnUrlRequest();
            options.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;




            EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, env);

            ViewUrl recipientView = envelopesApi.CreateSenderView(accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, options);


            return recipientView.Url.ToString();
        }
```

it gives this error:

`"The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."`

can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

An integration Key (API error message uses the old term "integrator key") must be used in the same environment. Did you create a Developer Sandbox integration Key? have you used it to obtain a token using OAuth consent flow?
Typically this error happens when you use the wrong key or point to the wrong environment

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not configuring your EnvelopesApi client, so there's no authentication info in the API call that's firing.

If you've already done authentication on an ApiClient, you can pass that configuration into the EnvelopesApi client like this:

```
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient.Configuration);
```

If you don't have authentication set up at all, I'd recommend referencing the auth code grant launcher: https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core

Comment: Hey that is not the issue, everything was working fine until I introduced `CreateSenderView` to open the envelope in the embedded view. It was sending the envelope via Email, I don't want that

Comment: So if you comment out the `ViewUrl recipientView = envelopesApi.CreateSenderView(accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, options);` line the envelope is created successfully?

Comment: Yes, If I don't do the `CreateSenderView` thing it sends an envelope to the customer via email